# Can I move defects from Quality Center to Bugzilla

Tags: move, bugzilla, hp-quality-center, defects

Have anyone migrated defects from Quality Center to Bugzilla? If so, can you tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can export all to Excel and import it back in Bugzilla.
There could also be some scripts available.